# How to give space between two Table Rows In Material-UI Table Row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
  root: ({ open }) => ({
    backgroundColor: open ? "#F5F6FF" : "white",
    backgroundOrigin: "border-box",
    spacing: 8,
    "& > *": {
      height: "64px",
      borderSpacing: "10px 10px ",
      borderCollapse: "separate",
    },
  }),
});
<TableRow className={classes.root}>
     cell content will comes here
<TableRow>
```

this is the CSS I am using with `TableRow` Material-UI but it is not working

Can anybody tell me how I can add space between rows in Material-UI TableRows

I have found many similar question but they are not working in my case

here I have recreated this issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leftpad-7jnhv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is it possible for you make a small runable snippet on a pen somewhere in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sure i will edit my question. and will add a sandbox link.

Comment: Try have the parent container display flex and have a gap property as well `gap: 1.5rem;` or something like that. It's an "okay" supported property. https://caniuse.com/?search=gap

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leftpad-7jnhv?file=/src/App.js . this is the sandbox link

Comment: no gap is also no working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your `TableRow` inside `Table` component and in your `TableRow` container, add the following styles, it will set the border bottom in every row except the last one:

```
const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
  tableBody: {
    "& > :not(:last-child)": {
      borderBottom: "25px solid red"
    }
  }
});
```

```
<TableBody className={classes.tableBody}>
  <TableRow>
    {...}
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    {...}
  </TableRow>
</TableBody>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]